# Can AWS amplify connect to a private RDS resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-amplify

I am building a webapp using NextJS. This app will have a backend with datastore that I am planning to use as AWS RDS PSQL. This RDS instance will be private within a VPC and not publicly available, now in AWS Amplify, I don't see any options for VPC, so was wondering on how the NextJS backend code connect to AWS RDS instance?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/3362) on the aws-amplify GitHub, this is currently not possible. In fact, the aws team has marked the possibility of adding an Amplify hosting app to a VPC as a **feature request**, as you can see in [this other issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/794).

As of today, I could not find more information as to whether (and when) it is planned to add such a feature to AWS Amplify.